# Does google-translate support CORS?

Tags: javascript, post, google-translate, cors

Is it possible to access google-translate (API v2) using

- Javascript
- POST
- Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)

It is quite easy to do it with GET, but the URL is limited to 2k characters (more like 2072).

The string to be translated is encoded with encodeURIComponent. That means the actual length of the string is less than 360 characters (greek). It seems that I can go from 360 ch to 5.000 ch using POST that is quite an improvement.

I know that I can call my server and have it call google-translate but it seems to be overkill if a CORS solution is feasible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can.  The [documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/nl/apis/language/translate/v2/using_rest.html#WorkingResults) states that:

> You can also use POST to invoke the
>   API if you want to send more data in a
>   single request. The `q` parameter in
>   the POST body must be less than 5K
>   characters. To use POST, you must use
>   the `X-HTTP-Method-Override` header to
>   tell the Translate API to treat the
>   request as a GET (use
>   `X-HTTP-Method-Override: GET`).

Since that API also supports a [callback](http://code.google.com/intl/nl/apis/language/translate/v2/using_rest.html#callback) parameter, you can create a JSONP request, which means you can get it cross-domain.

Can't you make a request with jQuery’s [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method make a request with `dataType: "jsonp"` and `type: "POST"`?

Mind you, I haven’t tested this.

Comment: Yes, I have read the documentation. I will give it a shot with javascript but I was wondering if anyone has done it.

Comment: Any info on *how* you set the header?

Comment: @Elisabeth: jQuery's [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method also has a `headers` option, where you can specify any custom header. Mind you, you’ll need jQuery 1.5 or higher to use this.